# JTree two nodes with same name can't be differentiated with getSelectedPath

Tags: java, swing, tree, jtree

I have two working JTrees and i can edit/delete/add nodes by drag and drop from one tree to another. 
But one of my trees has two nodes with same name. Irrelevant to which of the two nodes I select, the deletion always delete the first node based on the name. 
I cant give numbers since nested nodes have complexity on defining it.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: By fixing the code. If you showed it, maybe we could help.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it uses `equals()` method of the objects. Try to override the method to provide the difference between nodes with the same name.